# Get function return type in template

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

How can I get return type for any function passed to template?
I don't know how to convert between `template<typename T>` and `template<typename Result, typename Args...>`:

```
template<typename T>
void print_name(T f)
{
    static_assert(internal::is_function_pointer<T>::value
            || std::is_member_function_pointer<T>::value,
            "T must be function or member function pointer.");
    typename decltype(f(...)) Result; // ???
    typename std::result_of<T>()::type Result; // ???
    printf("%s\n", typeid(Result).name());
}

void f_void() {}
int f_int(int x) { return 0; }
float f_float(int x, int y) { return 0.f; }
struct X { int f(int x, float y) { return 0; } };

int main()
{
    print_name(f_void);
    print_name(f_int);
    print_name(f_float);
    print_name(&X::f);
    return 0;
}
```

How can i get type `Result` inside function `print_name`?

Comment: If what you're trying to reach is to get the result into a variable without knowing its type in advance, a simple  

`auto a = f(x); `
should be enough.

Comment: @JanNilsFerner I suspect he hasn't the parameters to be used for the call.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A possible solution is using a function declaration that *extracts* the return type as well as all the parameters. You don't have even to define it.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<typeinfo>
#include<cstdio>

template<typename R, typename... A>
R ret(R(*)(A...));

template<typename C, typename R, typename... A>
R ret(R(C::*)(A...));

template<typename T>
void print_name(T f)
{
    printf("%s\n", typeid(decltype(ret(f))).name());
}

void f_void() {}
int f_int(int x) { return 0; }
float f_float(int x, int y) { return 0.f; }
struct X { int f(int x, float y) { return 0; } };

int main()
{
    print_name(f_void);
    print_name(f_int);
    print_name(f_float);
    print_name(&X::f);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the declarations provided for `ret` has the same return type of the submitted function or member function.
A `decltype` does the rest.

Comment: Is this SFINAE?

Comment: @Thomas I would say overloading.

Comment: Isn't there anything in the standard library which does what ret does?

Comment: @einpoklum It depends on the revision of the standard. At the time I wrote this, I'm tempted to say _no_.

Comment: @skypjack: How about C++17 then?

Comment: @einpoklum Not sure indeed. The first thing that comes to my mind is `std::invoke_result`, but it's not suitable for the purpose for you should not what are the arguments to use to invoke it.

Comment: Don't work with `struct X { int f(int x, float y) const { return 0; } };` though easily fixed

Comment: What is the purpose of the `template<typename C, typename R, typename... A>` version of `ret`?

Comment: @BenJones to capture member functions. The other version accepts only free functions instead.

Answer (score 12):

[as of C++ 17, the answer is](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of)

```
std::invoke_result_t<T>
```

Comment: The linked reference says this was introduced in C++17, is there a relevant change in C++20?