# How can I retrieve the return type of a function to use in a template?

Tags: c++, function, return-type, c++-templates

I have a function somewhere called `x` that returns a know value and has known parameters:

```
int x(int y);
```

I have somewhere else, I want to create a container to contain `n` invocations of this function. Then I want to execute it that many times.

The problem is, I don't want to rely on it being an `int` return type. I need to deduce the return type at compile time. Something like:

```
std::vector<result_of<x(int)>::type> results;
```

But I don't want to have to specify the parameter values because they're static.

Comment: [This StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310898/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-a-variable) might answer your question.

Comment: You could take a look at the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41301717/2378300

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your own traits, something like:

```
template <typename F> struct my_result_of;

template <typename F> struct my_result_of<F*> : my_result_of<F> {};

template <typename Ret, typename ... Ts>
struct my_result_of<Ret(Ts...)>
{
    using type = Ret;
};

template <typename F> using my_result_of_t = typename my_result_of<F>::type;
```

And use it like (assuming no overloads of `x`):

```
std::vector<my_result_of_t<decltype(x)>::type> results;
```

Answer (score 5):

You are close. Assuming `T` is the template argument of the caller function:

```
std::vector<decltype(x(std::declval<T>()))> results;
```

Comment: [This does not work.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/755fc639873ce270) Did you test your solution?

Comment: @cpplearner: your point. That's not how result_of works. Changed to `decltype`.

Comment: "template argument of the caller function"? The function wishing to call `x` doesn't have a template argument.

Comment: Then it's not possible to get the return type of `x`, if it isn't a function but an overload set. If there isn't any overload tough, there isn't much point of deducing the return type either.

Answer (score 3):

You can abuse `std::function::result_type`:

```
int x(int y);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int,std::function<decltype(x)>::result_type>);
```

Of course this will only work if `x` is really a function. If `x` is an arbitrary function object, then its result type may depend on its argument type, in which case you cannot know its result type without specifying the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you can use up to the most recent standard revision, for you didn't specify it.
Here is a minimal, working example:

```
#include<vector>
#include<functional>
#include<utility>

template<std::size_t... I, typename F, typename... A>
auto gen(std::index_sequence<I...>, F &&f, A... args) {
    return std::vector<decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(args...))>{
        (I, std::forward<F>(f)(args...))...
    };
}

template<std::size_t N, typename F, typename... A>
auto gen(F &&f, A... args) {
    return gen(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, std::forward<F>(f), args...);
}

int f(int, char) { return 0; }

int main() {
    auto vec = gen<10>(&f, 0, 'c');
}
```

Return type of your function is easily deduced by:

```
decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(args...))
```

> I want to create a container to contain n invocations of this function. Then I want to execute it that many times.

To do that, I used an `std::index_sequence` to create a parameter pack having the right size.
Then the vector itself is initialized as it follows:

```
(I, std::forward<F>(f)(args...))...
```

The basic idea is to exploit the comma operator to unpack the parameter pack mentioned above and execute `N` times the function. The values returned by the invokations of `f` are used to fill the vector.

Note that `args` are not perfectly forwarded to `f`.
It could cause problems in case of moveable objects consumed during the first execution.