# Accessing the return type of a method

Tags: c++, type-traits, invoke-result

I'm having a hard time getting this simple thing going.

One thing I found that works:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    int Method();
};

static_assert(  std::is_same_v<
        decltype(A{}.Method()), int
    >
); // pass. cool.
```

Ok great. But no; not great. Because I now have a default constructible requirement, AND I need to write a call expression with all arguments. And who knows about them !

Consider the real situation:

```
struct A
{
    int Method(MysteriousArgumentsIDontCareAboutAndCanChangeInTheFuture);
};

static_assert(  std::is_same_v<
        decltype(A{}.Method()), int
    >
);  // not so cool anymore (too few arguments to function call, expected 1, have 0)
```

How about using `std::invoke_result` ?

```
static_assert(  std::is_same_v<
        std::invoke_result_t< A::Method >, int
    >
);
```

nah.

> call to non-static member function without an object argument

MSVC says

> non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

I can fiddle all I want with this expression, nothing good comes out of it.
e.g.:

```
using T = std::invoke_result_t< decltype(&A::Method) >;
```

> error: no type named 'type' in 'std::invoke_result

If I remove the `decltype` it's type-value mismatch (of course) etc...

cppreference.com mentions this usage for the C++14 version:

```
std::result_of<decltype(&C::Func)(C, char, int&)>::type
```

Not much better than my first attempt. All the arguments are still there.
In action in our simple case: https://godbolt.org/z/KtQbth

Help ?

Comment: While on potty break I realized that I'm chasing a chimera because the arguments are part of the callable's identity. Since callables can be overloaded. Seems like I'll have to bite the bullet

Comment: Still, with all these "if" rules in the language spec, like: "if" no non-template overload match, then consider templates, then "if" a template matched, consider specifications... Isn't it the same to add a rule to address callable symbols by half their identify as long as it ends in a unique lookup... darn C++

Comment: At `result_of` `A` is missing as first arg: `using T = std::result_of<decltype(&A::Method)(A,Mysterious)>::type;` at `invoke_result` you don't pass ArgTypes at all `using T = std::invoke_result< decltype(&A::Method), A, Mysterious>::type;`.

Comment: @rafix07 thanks. I'll fix-edit that part to avoid pollute the question into 2 questions

Comment: Have you checked this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301536/get-function-return-type-in-template? It still doesn't work for overloaded functions without a static cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the trait suggested by [Piotr Skotnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26201959/5376789):

```
template <typename T>
struct return_type;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(*)(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) &> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) &&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename T>
using return_type_t = typename return_type<T>::type;
```

Now you can do:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<return_type_t<decltype(&A::Method)>, int>);
```

Comment: seems like that's it. also it seems like https://stackoverflow.com/q/26201835/893406 is an exact repost ? should close mine I guess

Comment: @v.oddou I don't think it is a duplicate. That question asks how to get the return type from a **type** while yours asks how to get the return type from the method name.

Comment: Me who was thinking `result_of` / `invoke_result` was a standardization of that `return_type` trait... how naive of me. WG underdelivers again ?

Answer (score 0):

```
[static_assert( std::is_same_v< decltype(std::declval<A>().Method()), int >);//super cool now][1]
```

Comment: doesn't work for this reason: https://godbolt.org/z/e__YpV
:)) seems like there is a way using partial specialization destructuring though, as @xskxzr is proposing.

Comment: @v.oddou your test case is different from the OP. Try this: decltype(std::declval<A>().Method(std::declval<Mysterious>()))

Comment: result_of would be  one choice, if only it were not deprecated.